# How to call BizTalk Server when Inserting new row into SQL table?

Tags: sql, insert, biztalk

I need to create the interaction of the two SQL-table using the BizTalk Server

The simplest example is when a new record is added to one table. Is it possible to call the BizTalk, transfer this row to BizTalk-solution, where it row will process and transfer to another SQL-table?

I found some information about BizTalk-To-SQL interaction, but i cannot find any information or example about SQL-to-BizTalk interaction.

If it possible, can you say - how, or give me some instruction?

Comment: You can use `replication` if your DBMS is supported. Is it forced to use BizTalk?

Comment: I do not think your solution is BizTalk. To my mind you need to develop an ETL. BizTalk is using for EAI (Enterprise Application Integration). I suggest you to review the problem and think about that, is your problem need to solve by EAI solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  But it is not possible for use to give detailed instructions based on your question.

You would have to have a receive location that either polls for records in that table, either inline SQL in the receive location or a call a Stored Procedure.

Then you would do whatever transformation etc. you needed using maps, possibly  Orchestrations, and have a send port that would insert it into another table.

How to [Configure a port using the WCF-SQL adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sql/configure-a-port-using-the-wcf-sql-adapter)

However, as others have said in the comments, you have to consider if BizTalk is a best fit of this.  This would depend on the frequency, what sort of processing is needed, how quickly after insert the record needs to be processed, number of rows, and if each row is a discreet message or a large group of records.

Some other possibilities to consider include

- Insert trigger on the first table, if you need it processed instantly
- A SSIS package running on a schedule, if it is a large batch of messages that needs to be processed on a schedule basis